# Shorten: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (p + (1-p) \frac{p(k-1) + 2}{2})$

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (p + (1-p) \frac{p(k-1) + 2}{2})$$

Attempt:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} p + \frac{(1-p)}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(p(k-1)+  2) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} p + \frac{p(1-p)}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1) + \frac{(1-p)}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2$$

what now ?

Comment: The first term is $np$ and the third is $n(1-p)$. The second sum is $n(n+1)/2 -n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (p + (1-p) \frac{p(k-1) + 2}{2}) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (1-(1-p) + (1-p) \frac{p(k-1) + 2}{2})$

$=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (1 +(1-p)(\frac{p(k-1) + 2}{2} -1)) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (1 + (1-p)(\frac{p(k-1)}{2}))$

$= n+\frac{p(1-p)}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1) = n+\frac{p(1-p)}{2}\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$